# Meaning of PLSQL symbol "=>"

Tags: oracle, plsql

What does the `=>` symbol mean in PL/SQL? e.g.

```
GetAttrNumber(toitemtype => toitemtype,
              toitemkey => toitemkey,
              toactid => toactid)
```

Comment: And I quote "Association operator for positional notation"

Answer (score 30):

That is the keyword/value notation for passing parameters to a PL/SQL procedure or function.

The left side is the name of the parameter, the right is the value being passed.

It's useful when you don't want to keep to a specific ordering of parameters, or for self-documenting code.

Answer (score 15):

The keyword/value notation can be very useful if you have a long list of parameters and only need to specify subset of them. Especially if you want to skip some of the parameters in the middle of the list of parameters [(this requires the skipped parameters to use DEFAULT values)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg10pck.htm#832). As an example if you have a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE my_proc(
    p_param1  NUMBER DEFAULT 1
  , p_param2  NUMBER DEFAULT 2
  , p_param3  NUMBER DEFAULT 3
  , p_param4  NUMBER DEFAULT 4
  , p_param5  NUMBER DEFAULT 5 
);
```

Now you can [call my_proc() only with only first and last parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg10pck.htm#2482),

my_proc(p_param1 => value1, p_param5 => value2);

Comment: In your examples, the parameters need to be declared with a `default`, for example `p_param4 number default 4` or `p_param4 number := 4`.